# Php header redirection is working on localhost but not on server?

Tags: php, mysql, database

hi guys im trying with this code to enforce redirection to login form if session is not started, localy it works, but in online server it doesnt, what am i supposed to do please help, here is the code :

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != "true") {
     header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: perhaps you have a blank line after a closing ?>

Comment: Whenever something doesn't work, add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop your script.

Comment: Note: HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.

Comment: i tried error reporting stuff, it just dont give any error, when i add exit; or die(), it just gives me blank page..

Comment: Try adding a / before login.php like: header("Location: /login.php");

Comment: @naruto tried, not working still..

Comment: Without any validation did you just check `header("Location: login.php");` the redirection whether it's work at all or not?

Comment: used this as alternative and worked, :  <?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != "true") {
  print('<script>window.location = "login.php"</script>');
}
?>

Comment: @Tahi Don't rely on JavaScript mate. Try to figure out header forwarding is not working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
     header("Location: login.php");
}

?>
```

Also check what is the value of `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` by echoing. Also enable `error_reporting` if it still not working

Comment: what is the value of `echo $_SESSION['loggedIn']` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try a else condition also, so that you can know the where the condition gone.

Also don't make new line space before session start function and before session start function write ob_start(); also

Comment: <?php ob_start(); session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] != "true") {
     header("Location: login.php");
} else { echo "test"; }
?>
What is the output you are getting ??

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
     header("Location: login.php");
     exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: when i add the exit; , it just gives me a blank page and not redirecting it.. if i dont add exit it just doesnt redirect but loading the page. Please helpp !! what can i do

Comment: have you login.php in the same path or not/